# ArrayList with more 10 items saved not ordered to DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, arraylist

I receive `List<MyDto> dtos` with 14 `MyDto` and try to save it to the database.

1. I receive `List<MyDto>`
2. loop `dtos` and on each step:

   2.1 -> map `MyDto` to `MyEntity`

   2.2) -> save and flush `MyEntity` to DB

I expect 14 rows in DB, saved in the order in which I saved. For example:

```
row0
row1
row2
row3
row4
row5
row6
row7
row8
row9
row10
row11
row12
row13
```

It works fine on all instances of application with PostgreSQL and Oracle.

But On one instance which works with Oracle, I have strange behavior. Sometimes, the order is broken. I don't understand why? All rows save with an offset.

If I save the above example I have this:

```
row4
row5
row6
row7
row8
row9
row10
row11
row12
row13
row0
row1
row2
row3
```

I thought that the matter in the `ArrayList`. It has `DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10` and if I add 14 items - it changes `CAPACITY` and items reordered. But I don't understand the next:

1. Why it happens sometimes and doesn't happen on other machines?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: ArrayList won't reorder when the capacity increases. So I assume the "problem" is only in the database. And what do you mean by "order"? If you don't specify any "order by" clause, the order of rows returned from select is not deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because of the thread pool which Oracle uses for operations.  Try adding a pause in between your inserts to see if that's your issue.

As a long-term fix, you probably don't want to be depending on insert order directly for record ordering if you plan to scale.  You should probably be using a sequence ID or object creation date or something else to order your records on select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@OrderBy** annotation (on the top of the property you to sort by) from JPA to get your list in the order you want.

For further information check this link [jpa/OrderBy](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OrderBy)